# Bot no longer working

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, bad-gateway

My bot stopped working a while ago out of the blue, I hadn't changed anything in the code/settings. Now all I get is 'Sorry, my bot code is having an issue' messages.

I believe the issue could be from hitting the LUIS quota limit (I got an email saying I was about to hit it the day before it went down), but have upgraded the LUIS and App Service plans and it still won't work. Tried making new bots from scratch and they all have the same error, but one of my other LUIS bots which is still working fine.

[502 bad gateway error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SXgZ.png)

Also tried debugging locally only to get the same 502 gateway error. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing it or how I could dig further to find the source of it?

Comment: Could you please check the channels tab on your azure portal and see if any errors are coming through there? It might help provide details to debug this situation.

Comment: `one of my other LUIS bots which is still working fine` Does it use same Luis app and App Service plan with other Luis bots? Besides, you can try to create a basic bot application and test if same issue appears.

Comment: To calrify @pjacca01, are you testing your bot via Web Chat in Azure or are you using the emulator and getting this error? If emulator, did you ensure that you updated the AppId and Password in the Bot Configuration?

Comment: or rather, as Mark B had asked, what channel are you use precisely to communicate with your bot?